# Does the alpha effect apply to third row elements?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, organosulfur-compounds

Alkylperoxy anions are stronger nucleophiles than alkoxides (the so-called alpha effect), but would an alkyldisulfide anion be a better nucleophile than an alkylthiolate anion?